# SQLAlchemy Aggregate sum of related table column values

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have tables:

```
class Cart(Base):
    items = relationship('Item', backref='cart')

class Item(Base):
    price = sa.Column(sa.Integer, default=0)
    cart_id = sa.Column(
        sa.Integer,
        sa.ForeignKey(
            'Cart.id',
            ondelete='CASCADE',
        )
    )
```

I want to aggregate sum of cart items price and order carts list by this aggregated sum. How I can build query in SA?

Answer (score 2):

You can implement it as a hybrid property (you have to set also relationship differently by adding  `lazy='dynamic'`).

```py
from sqlalchemy import func, select

class Cart(Base):
    items = relationship("Item", backref="cart", lazy="dynamic")

    @hybrid_property
    def items_price(self):
        return self.items.with_entities(func.sum(Item.price)).scalar()

    @items_price.expression
    def items_price(cls):
        return (
            select(func.sum(Item.price))
            .where(Item.cart_id == cls.id)
            .label("items_price")
        )


class Item(Base):
    price = Column(Integer, default=0)
    cart_id = Column(
        Integer,
        ForeignKey(
            "Cart.id",
            ondelete="CASCADE",
        ),
    )
```

You can now use `items_price` in a query:

```py
carts = session.query(Cart).order_by(Cart.items_price.desc())
```

However, the performance of this approach is not great. So if your db is large, you should try something like that:

```py
cart_price = func.sum(Item.price)
# result query is a list of tuples (<cart_id>, <cart_price>)
carts_price = session.query(
    Item.cart_id,
    cart_price
).group_by(
    Item.cart_id
).order_by(
    cart_price.desc()
)
```